# how to draw a line (between pushpins) exactly over the railroad in bing map

Tags: bing-maps

Here is my map of between points based on latitude & longitude.
[image]

if you observe the line and rail road carefully you see, the railroad is not straight line but the line i draw between pushpins are straight. But i need my drawing lines should be over the rail road. i am not sure whether it's possible or not. if possible please advice.
And here is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Crossing Map</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 var map = null;
 var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
 var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();

 function GetMap() {
    // Initialize the map
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),{
            credentials:"API Key"               
          }); 

    // Create the info box for the pushpin
    pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false });
    infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);

    //created variables(one variable per location)
    var loc1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.775560, -95.348878);
      // Add a pin to the map
      var pin1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc1); 
      pin1.Title = "Brooks St";
      pin1.Description = "First PIn Descriptoin is here.";
      pinLayer.push(pin1); //add pushpin to pinLayer
      Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin1, 'click', displayInfobox);
      var loc2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.776584, -95.348878);

      // Add a pin to the map
      var pin2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc2); 
      pin2.Title = "Harrington St";
      pin2.Description = "Second pin description";
      pinLayer.push(pin2); //add pushpin to pinLayer
      Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin2, 'click', displayInfobox);
      var loc3 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.778530, -95.348663);

      // Add a pin to the map
      var pin3 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc3); 
      pin3.Title = "Loraine St";
      pin3.Description = "Third pin desc";
      pinLayer.push(pin3); //add pushpin to pinLayer
      Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin3, 'click', displayInfobox);
      var loc4 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.783419, -95.348963);

      // Add a pin to the map
      var pin4 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc4); 
      pin4.Title = "Quitman St";
      pin4.Description = "pin 4 desc";
      pinLayer.push(pin4); //add pushpin to pinLayer
      Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin4, 'click', displayInfobox);
      var loc5 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.802104, -95.342655);

      // Add a pin to the map
      var pin5 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc5); 
      pin5.Title = "Calvalcade";
      pin5.Description = "5th pin desc";
      pinLayer.push(pin5); //add pushpin to pinLayer
      Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin5, 'click', displayInfobox);

    // Create a polyline        
    var lineVertices = new Array(loc1,loc2,loc3,loc4,loc5);  //var lineVertices = new Array(loc1, loc2, loc3);

    var line = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(lineVertices);

    //map.setView({center:loc2, zoom: 9} );
    map.setView({center:loc2, zoom: 15} );

    map.entities.push(line);
    map.entities.push(pinLayer);
    map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);
 }

function displayInfobox(e) {
    pinInfobox.setOptions({
        title: e.target.Title, 
        description: e.target.Description, 
        visible:true, 
        offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,25)
    });
    pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
}

function hideInfobox(e) {
    pinInfobox.setOptions({ visible: false });
}
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="GetMap();">
<div class="wapper">
<div class="contentareaNoM safetybg">
<div id="core">
  <div id='mapDiv' style="positio:relative; margin-left:100px; width:800px; height:800px;"></div>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the polyline (with coordinates) that corresponds to your railroad then you will be able to draw onto those elements. In this way, you will be able to have every point of the railway.

You can take a look at OpenStreetMap that include those element with precise geometry information where the coverage is good.

Comment: I already using polyline with coordinates. but the problem is it always draw a straight line between two pushpins. but i wanted the line become curve and should go over rail road. is it possible using bing map?
On the other hand, if i use hundreds of coordinates which are between two pushpin then my map will only show only pushpin and pushpin. is there are any way to use coordinate to draw line but hide pushpin?

Comment: No, the pushpin are different from the line coordinate itself, take a look at the interactive SDK here to understand how it works: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#Shapes2